# logstash as service on red hat 5 error?

Tags: elasticsearch, installation, redhat, logstash

I am trying to run `logstash 1.4.1` as a service on my red hat 5.3. So I do the following

```
rpm -ivh logstash-1.4.1-1_bd507eb.noarch.rpm
```

when I run service logstash start it gives logstash started and when I check service logstash status it gives logstash is not running.

I check `/var/log/logstash/logstash.err` and it has:

```
chroot: invalid option -- -
Try `chroot --help' for more information.
```

inside this.

Answer (score 0):

Get another init.d script, like [this one](https://gist.github.com/slojo404/2228905).